# std::fstream on windows network share

Tags: c++

I am struggling reading files from windows network shares.
I have a network share mounted as `S:`
so my code looks something like this:

```
std::fstream in;
in.open("S:/adir/new folder/afile.txt", std::fstream::in);
if (in.fail())
    throw "failed";
...  //use in for reading
```

When I first run this program, it throws "failed". It keeps failing until I navigate the windows explorer to that directory, after that, it works.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need `in.open("\\\\server\\shared\\file", std::fstream::in);`

Comment: The drive is probably not permanently mounted, and is mounted by navigating explorer to it.

Comment: @Peter is there a way to check that, it might be anything due IT installation

Comment: Using the win API, yes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363940(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a file, the system executing the code should have access to the share or mapped network drive at the time of execution.

The [`WNetAddConnection2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function makes a connection to a network resource and can redirect a local device to the network resource.

```
DWORD dwRetVal;
NETRESOURCE nr;
DWORD dwFlags;

// Zero out the NETRESOURCE struct
memset(&nr, 0, sizeof (NETRESOURCE));

nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
nr.lpLocalName = <name of a local device>;
nr.lpRemoteName = <network resource to connect to>;
nr.lpProvider = NULL;

dwFlags = CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE;

// Call the WNetAddConnection2 function to assign
// a drive letter to the share.
dwRetVal = WNetAddConnection2(&nr,
                              <password to be used>,
                              <a user name>, 
                              dwFlags);

if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR)
    // Success ...
    // Now you can open the file
else
    // Failed ...
```

Comment: for some shares the `username` and `password` are the windows credentials, for others its something else. how to obtain this information (and why because windows explorer allready knows this information)?